# saving and getting arabic language in mysql using java

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, utf-8

While saving an Arabic word into mysql table, i am getting a string  starting with &# and each block have semicolon. am using jsp as front end, in jsp i can display the string in arabic, but while passing the string into form:input
the data is shown as some unreadable code.

I wasted lot much time while fixing this issue, maybe this is not an issue but how can i convert this into the actual Arabic word in Java?, any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: You consider if the entire field valve is HTML or XML. If so, and you want to transform it, such as extracting only the text nodes, use an HTML or XML library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are numeric HTML entities.

Probably the data stem from an HTML form. The browser sent the text inputs as numeric entities as the form did not indicate that the server accepts that encoding. Assuming UTF-8:

The HTML best should be in the correct encoding - just for good measure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

The form should tell that the server accepts the encoding, not needing numeric entities.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Repairs:

```
String s = ...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\&#((x[A-F0-9]+)|\\d+);");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String code = m.group(1);
    if (code.startsWith("x") || code.startsWith("X")) {
        code = "0" + code;
    }
    int codePoint = Integer.decode(code);
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    sb.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
s = sb.toString();
```

The numeric entities come in two forms: `&#65;` in base 10, and `&#x3F;` in base 16.

Alternatively probably [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4-java.lang.String-) works satisfactory.